# how to use onsen-ui 2.0 to use flat design on iOS and material on Android ?

Tags: material-design, onsen-ui

Onsen-ui 2.0 provides material and flat components. If we want to follow vendor design guidelines we should use material for android and flat for ios. How should I do without using full switch android or ios on my templates ?

Answer (score 2):

With Onsen 2.0, they are enabling this exact feature.  Onsen 2.0 will automatically detect the platform and switch between iOS and Material for you.  Check out this blog post from yesterday that explains it all in detail:  https://onsen.io/blog/what-is-material-design/

This is the relevant quote though from that link:

> We have also gone one step further by adding automatic styles. What
>   this means is that an Onsen UI app will use the Material Design
>   components when running on the Android platform while it automatically
>   switches to the flat design when running on iOS.

Comment: Yep, it seems they'll release "Automatic style switching based on platform" on 2.0 beta 7 (current is beta 6)

Comment: Looks like it will be coming soon though.  I am glad I was able to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

I will be waiting for Beta 7 , Have you decided the date of release. Switch based on platform is going to be a fantastic feature.